# Elasticsearch Join query

Tags: aws, nosql, elasticsearch

Estoy trabajando con Elastic Search y necesito crear una consulta avanzada. Parte de una app que estoy desarollando permite que negocios creen ofertas a un publico objetivo("Seguidores", "Clientes", "Seguidores o Clientes", "Publico") estas categorias deben establecer a quienes les aparecerá la oferta.
El problema es que esos datos lo tengo normalizado, es decir separado. Un indice contiene los documentos de los clientes, otro la relación que hay entre usuarios (Seguidores),  y por ultimo uno nuevo para las ofertas.

Como en Elasticsearch no se permiten consultas combinadas tipo Join SQL, estoy bloqueado en como proseguir para estructurar los datos de forma que pueda hacer la consulta antes mencionada. El objetivo es:

Si el publico objetivo es "publico":
Aparecerle a los usuarios que esten a 10km del negocio, a los usuarios que sigan el perfil del negocio o los usuarios que ya son clientes del negocio.

Si el publico objetivo es "Seguidores":
Solo aparecerle a los usuarios que siguen el perfil del negocio y no son clientes.

Si el publico objetivo es "Clientes":
Solo aparecerle a los usuarios que son clientes del negocio.

Si el publico objetivo es "Seguidores o Clientes":
Solo aparecerle a los usuarios que siguen el perfil del negocio y a los que ya han sido clientes.

Modelo de los documentos:

```
Relationship
{
  followerId: String
  followedId: String
}

Customer
{
  businessId: String
  userId: String
  etc...
}
Offer
{
  id: String
  businessId: String
  target: "Seguidores" | "Clientes" | "Seguidores o Clientes" | "Publico"
  location: Coordinates
  etc...
}
```

Edicion: Vale la pena mencionar que estoy trabajando con tecnologías de amazon y con DynamoDB como base de datos, tal vez alguna solución para problemas similares se pueda resolver con una herramienta de esa estructura, por ejemplo lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Lo siguiente es respecto de Elasticsearch 7.15

No es posible hacer joins en Elasticsearch tal como se hacen en una base relacional. Para obtener datos en los que necesitarías join en bases relacionales, en Elasticsearch necesitas [denormalizar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalizaci%C3%B3n_(base_de_datos)) los datos de alguna manera. Esto quiere decir que vas a necesitar que exista una redundancia. La alternativa a denormalizar es hacer dos o mas consultas con algún motor que permita ir uniendo las consultas parciales.

Voy a poner un ejemplo mas general que el que tienes así se entiende mejor. Supongamos que tenemos personas con ids y ids paises:

```
id | nombre | id_pais

1  | Juan   | 101
2  | Pedro  | 104
```

Tenemos por otro lado paises:

```
id_pais | nombre 

101     | Filipinas
104     | Panamá
```

**La relación paises/nombres es 1 --> N**

En una base de datos relacional para saber el nombre de pais que tiene cada persona haríamos algo como

```
select *  from nombres join paises on nombres.id_pais = paises.id_pais
```

En Elasticsearch esto no se puede hacer, hay que denormalizar estos datos, dicho de una forma coloquial, hay que juntarlos y directamente guardar algo como:

```
id | nombre | id_pais | nombre_pais
    
1  | Juan   | 101     |  Filipinas
2  | Pedro  | 104     |  Panamá
```

Otra opción para denormalizar, es usando otra estructura: el [nested field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) en donde guardamos los paises y dentro (anidado) las personas, *no estoy seguro si esta estructura es denormalizada o no estrictamente hablando*.

```
{
  "pais" : "panama",
  "personas" : [ 
    {
      "nombre" : "Pedro"
    },
    {
      "nombre" : "Juana"
    }
  ]
}
```

Existe otra posibilidad que es la del [join data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.15/parent-join.html) en donde se usa un campo para establecer una relacion padre/hijo ente documentos **del mismo indice**, si bien la palabra "join" nos recuerda al join de SQL, no es tan similar, empezando por el hecho de que los campos a "joinear" estan en el mismo índice.

Tenemos aún mas opciones que pueden aprovechar el hecho de que se puede consultar mas de un indice en una consulta, pero el nivel de complejidad ya nos muestra que estamos haciendo algo totalmente antinatural para lo que fue pensado el software. Es preferible adecuar los datos a la lógica en la que fue pensada la herramienta.